# how to avoid undefined offset errors while moving next page in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

am doing php online quiz application,i used to plan 20 questions per page,when am moving next page it shows undefined offset errors.i need to get all radio button selected values to evaluate with my answer array.am using post  method to get all selected radio button values.when am clicking next button of pagination,the selected values of radio buttons are automatically posted before i submit the button.i need to evaluate the questions and answers without the error undefined offset.please help anyone.here is my code.....

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');
mysql_select_db('quiz_apptitude');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age");
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else { 
    $pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 2; 

$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

if ($pn < 1) {
    $pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
    $pn = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age $limit") or die('error'); 
//$total=mysql_num_rows($sql2) ;
$i=0;
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 

   $Question[]=$row['prob_Question'];
$optA[]=$row['prob_OptionA'];
$optB[]=$row['prob_OptionB'];
$optC[]=$row['prob_OptionC'];
$optD[]=$row['prob_OptionD'];
$ans[]=$row['prob_Answer'];
$Qid[$i]=$row['prob_Qid'];

    $ans[$i]=$row['prob_Answer'];
    $r=$i+1;

    $outputList .= '<table><tr>
              <td> '.$r.' . '.$Question[$i].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$Qid[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>

              <td><input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optA[$i].'" $outputList .= ($optA[$i] == $_POST[$Qid][$i]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';/> 
                '.$optA[$i].'</td></tr>
                <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optB[$i].'" $outputList .= ($optB[$i] == $_POST[$Qid][$i]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';/>
                '.$optB[$i].'</td></tr>
             <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"  id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optC[$i].'"  $outputList .= ($optC[$i] == $_POST[$Qid][$i]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';/>
               '.$optC[$i].'</td></tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optD[$i].'"  $outputList .= ($optD[$i] == $_POST[$Qid][$i]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';    />
            '.$optD[$i].'</td></tr>

            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$ans[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$ans[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr></table>';

$i++;
}

$count=count($Qid);

$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){

    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    } 

    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '">Next</a> ';
    } 
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>online QiuZ</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.pagNumActive {
    color: #000;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
-->
</style>  
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
     <h2>Problem On Age</h2>
   </div> 
   <!--   <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php //echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>-->
      <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
      <form name="prob_age" id="prob_age" method="post" action="result-age.php" >
      <?php print "$outputList"; ?>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

      </form>
      </div>
    <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid undefined offset errors, for each array key that is potentially not set, you should first check to see if the value is set before using it.

```
if( isset($array[$key]) )
```

will return false if $array[$key] is undefined.

If you need this to be inline you can use an inline if like so

```
$string = '<someHtml>' . (isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : '') . '</someHtml>';
```

Maybe I've missed something in your code, but I don't understand why you are setting the array variables at the top of the while loop and then just using them inside the while loop anyway. Do you need the array variables outside of the while loop?

Also I would avoid storing lots of HTML in a PHP variable just to echo it out further down the page. You would be better off just outputting the HTML during the loop in the correct place.

```
... Some HTML 
<?php
while( $someLogicIsTue )
{
    ?>
    ... Some HTML
    <someHTML><?php echo $someVal; ?></someHtml>
    .... Some Html
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: how can i use this code if( isset($array[$key]) ) into my code,please guide to do this....

Comment: :how can i use this code if( isset($array[$key]) ) into my code,please guide to do this....

Comment: Which of your array items are showing as undefined, and I will be able to guide your further

Comment: @MajorCaiger- In my code i have 5 questions and answers,in that am showing two questions for each page.while am moving to next page it shows undefined offset errors in my result page.i enclosed my result page code as follows...for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
{ 

$type = $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''];
$_SESSION['a'][$i] = (int)$type;
 
if($_SESSION['a'][$i]==$ans[$i])
{
 $markcount=$_SESSION['mark']+1;
$_SESSION['mark']=$markcount;
}
}
echo $markcount;

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition for your array variable, to avoid undefined offset
 
`if(is_array($your_varible)){`
`echo $your_varible[$key];`
`}`

Comment: In my code i have 5 questions and answers,in that am showing two questions for each page.while am moving to next page it shows undefined offset errors in my result page.i enclosed my result page code as follows...please help me to recover from this prob.for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) { $type = $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].'']; $_SESSION['a'][$i] = (int)$type; if($_SESSION['a'][$i]==$ans[$i]) { $markcount=$_SESSION['mark']+1; $_SESSION['mark']=$markcount; } } echo $markcount;

Comment: can u please be clear what is this? $type = $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].'']; $Oid contains ??